# Programmatically make Android phone home button blink

Tags: android, eclipse

I was wondering if there is a way to make an Android phone home button blink. This is because a lot of models don't have an LED light for notifications like my Samsung Galaxy W. This is a problem for me, so the idea is to make the home button blink on notification.

Comment: No, it's not. At least, not in the default SDK. (It may be in one for HTC-only devices, for example.) Not all devices have a "real" home button (Galaxy Nexus), and some don't light up at all (Galaxy S2).

Comment: Likewise with what Eric said, you might have some luck with manufacturer specific SDKs to make the LED light blink (most phones have that, at least).

Comment: My guess would be this is included in part of a private API.  If it is possible, you might be able to figure it out via reflection, but there's no guarantee

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can do this.  Controlling the 'Home' button in this manner seems like it would be a security risk (for instance, you could pro-grammatically hide it if you wanted to lock someone in your app).

I am 99.9% sure you can't do what you are asking , which is why you are not finding it.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I found an app that lights a colored dot in the screen, wich produces the led effect. this wors for me. But it would be interesting to do it using the home button. But i think you´re right. no chance.